# how to make snap package use system library?

Tags: ubuntu, gimp, snap-package

I have some snap packages (for example gimp) use its own python interpreter. py2.7. In my own python-fu script I need to import numpy which is not available in this snap-package but available in native system. How could I let the snap package access my system python-numpy?

Comment: [Advanced Snap Usage](https://snapcraft.io/tutorials/advanced-snap-usage#1-introduction) may be able to help.

Comment: The system-files/content interface seems related, but it seems requires gimp snap package provide the plug. Snap seems quite restrict regarding customize/config the package.